# Run A function when user registered

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have two kinds of login form i.e. one as "individual" and the other as "entity". So when a user registered as entity, then only I want to run a function which will display "minimum product size as 1 m",otherwise for individual users it will show 10m and any user who has not registered, it also should show 10m.
(Here, the minimum product size is minimum product size a user can order)

```
function quantityForEntity() {
  var smv = order_selection.options[order_selection.selectedIndex].value;

  if (customer[note][type] != blank) {
    if (smv == "Sampling") {
      productQtySelector.setAttribute("value", "1");
      productQtySelector.setAttribute("min", "1");
      if (sampleOnlytext != null) {
        sampleOnlytext.style.display = "block";
        samplingPrice.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (sampleOnlytext != null) {
      sampleOnlytext.style.display = "none";
      samplingPrice.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What happened when you tried to run this code?

Comment: Check if you have a `user` object or any object with `entity` property, then do just like this `var minOrder = user.entity ? 1 : 10`

Comment: how i will check that a user registered as an individual or an entity?

Answer (score 0):

If you hope to access the customer information, then you had best be using some Liquid. So for your purposes, you could at least run this before your JS code.

```
{% if customer %}
   var customer = {{customer | json}};
{% endif %}
```

Note that this might not prove super useful, if you cannot see the note assigned to the customer from Shopify.

Also, you can do all this in pure Liquid and avoid all this messy Javascript since you have the customer and any related info on them in Liquid. So you'd setup all those rules in Liquid so that even before rendering the HTML it would be correct. Make your life easier. Do the right thing!